# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin code added but nothing is happening

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, mod-headers

I am trying to solve the below option on my website

```
Strict-Transport-Security
Content-Security-Policy 
X-Frame-Options 
X-Content-Type-Options 
Referrer-Policy 
Permissions-Policy
```

I found the below code on Google and added the same in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file. Also added the same code in .htaccess and restarted the server

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
  Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</IfModule>
```

but it's not working

I have scanned my website in this URL: https://securityheaders.com/,

Comment: What specifically are you trying to "solve"? The only directive that is relevant to your question is the `Header` directive, so why are you adding the rest? Both `Require` and `Order`/`Allow` directives should not be used at the same time (the first is Apache 2.4 and the second Apache 2.2). Is `/var/www/html` the correct directory? Are you not using virtualhosts? "See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details." - And what does that report?

Comment: @MrWhite, I have to solve those issues, so I researched Google and found the header code to add to the config file. so I have added the same code in the question and getting an error... The path is correct /var/www/html

Comment: @MrWhite, i am a beginner in AWS apache2, Both Require and Order/Allow directives should not be used at the same time // what code i have to use it?